# How do I inspect my variables when using node --inspect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I've got some code that is occasionally exhibiting unexpected behavior that is hard to reproduce.  I'm trying to see what is happening by running:

```
node --inspect client.js
```

It gives me a URL which I click, and then Chrome comes up with a console.  Now I wait for the bad state to be encountered, and then I want to inspect the value of various variables in main.js (which are in term other objects I can dig into) in order to try to figure out what is going on.

However, I can't see any of my variables!  I can see the `global` scope, but it has no variables from my code in it.  How can I introspect the state of my program without having to think too far ahead, i.e. I could expose some variable to the global scope and hope that doesn't cause any side-effects, but then what if the issue is occurring somewhere I didn't think to expose?  I want to set everything up and only have to run one time because this is a rather difficult problem to reproduce and may take a substantial amount of time, so once it gets into this state I have to be able to do everything I need to find the problem without losing the current program state.

Edit: Also to add, placing breakpoints is not necessarily helpful, because everything is event driven, and these is no guarantee I can trigger an event, or that it won't change the state in a way the interferes with trying to determine why the program is in a bad state, or that I can see the scope I need to look at from the scope where the event occurs.

Update: I tried adding a bit of code in my main module and then exporting all the top-level variables:

```
global.main=module
module.exports = {
   var1:var1,
   ...
   var99:var99
}
```

This part seemed to work ok, but I still don't have access the to internal state of objects.  To accomplish this, I tried adding a debug function to each object which simply had a debugger statement to stop the debugger, like so:

```
function SomeOjbect(...) {
   var me = this
    ...
    me.debug = function() {
        console.log("In debugger")
        debugger
    }
    ...
}
```

The theory being that at this point all the local variables closed to the object would be inspectable.  However, when I hit the debug statement and get a breakpoint, the inspection tools completely ignore all my efforts to inspect variables in the object - in the console I get no output, just another prompt, while in the watch window after I type in the variable and hit enter it disappears completely, as if I never even tried to enter a new variable.  This happens even if I mention the name of the variable in the code before hitting the debugger to try to prevent it from being optimized out, e.g. when I change the above code to this:

```
console.log("In debugger")
me;
debugger
```

I still am unable to inspect `me`.  (It does, however, print `me` to the console if I replace `me;` with `console.log(me)`!)

Update: Actually, it appears that I'm able to do *nothing at all* in the breakpoint.  If I enter `console.log("Test")` in the console, it doesn't output anything either.  If I let the code continue running, the commands I entered into the console don't even show up in history, and in fact I no longer am able to enter any new commands at all, they all continue to be ignored, and sometimes in the source tab all source code vanishes and I pretty much have to shut down the running program and start over because the debugger becomes useless.

Comment: Did you read the [instructions on how to use the debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)? You can't just start typing things when the debugger pauses, you need to explicitly first enter REPL mode (short for "read, evaluate, print, loop") by typing `repl` before you can start typing code and have it evaluated with a console log for the result.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That appears to be for the command-line debugger?  I've tried that too (I get "no frame" so I apparently can't even inspect anything without a breakpoint), but what I'm trying to do right now is running an inspector/console in Chrome.

Comment: In that case it's time to create a [mcve] - 90% of the time that exercise actually lets you discover the problem on your own, but the remaining 10% of the time it means you have excellent minimal code that you can drop into a post to go "this should work, but doesn't" without needing someone to clone a full project to reproduce and comment on.

Comment: Do you find a solution?